# Javascript Ninja: Current element in array as function context

Tags: javascript, function, call

I'm trying to wrap my head around some code in Javascript ninja on page 57.

```
function forEach(list, callback) {
    for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
        callback.call(list[n], n); //makes the current element the function context of callback???
    }
}

var weapons = ['shuriken', 'katana', 'nunchucks'];

forEach(weapons,
    function(index) {
        assert(this == weapons[index], "Got the expected value of " + weapons[index]);
    }
);
```

I can pass the index of the array in the callback without using the call method and that makes  sense. What I don't understand is why would I want to use the current element as the function context. What is this trying to accomplish?

I also am having a hard time understanding how this could be done. I'm assuming that the call method is looking at the list item as an object and not as the element in the array. But I'm not sure that's correct.

My other thought was that by not assigning the function context to the current element the function context would be the `forEach` function. I'm not sure what trouble that would cause if any and maybe that had something to do with the reason for changing the function context.

Comment: Is that the _exact_ code?  To do what it's attempting to do, I would expect the function call in the for loop to be something like `callback.call(list[n],n)` - Note the extra `.call`

Comment: ah ya your right. I missed that thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph ("I am having a hard time..."). Could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: JLRishe - sorry I'm kind of new to this. So the call method takes a function context as it's first parameter and then an argument list. My thought process is that the function context has to be within an object and I'm confused because it looks like the function context is an element in the array and I don't understand how that could be.

Comment: @rmares2 The function context that you pass to `call()` (or `apply()`, or `bind()`) can be anything at all. It can be `null`, `0`, or `"howdy"` if you want it to be. It simply determines what the value of `this` is going to be when the function executes (_most_ of the time...). The `this` keyword in JavaScript is, by and large, just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for an implicit function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why would I want to use the current element as the function context.

What this allows you to do is use `this` in the callback function to refer to each respective current element. This is the same convention that the jQuery [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method and some other jQuery methods use (the author of your book was the creator of jQuery).

It allows you to do this:

```
forEach([1, 2, 3], function() {
    console.log(this * 2);      // 'this' refers to the current element
});
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
```

Of course, another perfectly fine approach is to pass in the current element as an argument and not specify a function context. This is what the built-in `Array.prototype.forEach` does (essentially). A simplified version of that approach would look like this:

```
function forEach(list, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        callback(list[i], i);
    }
}

forEach([1, 2, 3], function(item) {
    console.log(item * 2);   // 'item' is the current element
});
```

Neither approach is definitively better than the other. It's simply that some find being able to use `this` for this purpose more convenient.

> I also am having a hard time understanding how this could be done. I'm assuming that the call method is looking at the list item as an object and not as the element in the array. But I'm not sure that's correct.

The function context passed to `call()` can be anything at all. It simply determines the value that `this` takes on when the function executes (*most* of the time).

> My other thought was that by not assigning the function context to the current element the function context would be the forEach function.

No, if the function context were unspecified here, it would be `null` in strict mode, or `window` in quirks mode (assuming the code was running in a browser). Neither would be particularly useful here.

> I'm not sure what trouble that would cause if any and maybe that had something to do with the reason for changing the function context.

It would only cause trouble if someone tried to use `this` in their callback in any meaningful way. The reason for changing it is what I explained above.

Comment: That it's a jQuery convention doesn't make it better…

Comment: @Bergi I never said (nor implied) that it does.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to emphasize that it's one jQuery's poorer ones

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, it doesn't sit quite right with me either. It's especially bad that they couldn't keep the order of callback parameters consistent between `$.each`, `$.map`, and `$.grep`, perhaps as a side-effect of this stylistic choice. But it's kinda nifty nonetheless.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks thats exactly what I was looking for it makes better sense now.